# Ir a un spinner y desplegarlo después de poner la fecha del Calendar en un EditText

Tags: android

Tengo un EditText que abre un Calendar, cuando el usuario pone la fecha que quiere y presiona "Aceptar" que está en el Calendar este se cierra poniendo en el EditText la fecha que puso(esto es correcto), pero luego presiona en el teclado "Sig."(Siguiente) para ir al siguiente widget que es un Spinner pero no despliega el Spinner, lo que hace es irse al EditText que está debajo del Spinner.

**¿Cómo podría hacer que vaya al Spinner y lo despliegue después de hacer la operación respectiva en el Calendar?**

Este es el código que tengo ahora

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends BaseActivity {
  Calendar myCalendar;
  EditText edt_birthdate;
  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

    edt_birthdate= findViewById(R.id.edt_birthdate);

    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);
            edt_birthdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
          }

      };

      edt_birthdate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                new DatePickerDialog(EditProfileActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        }
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando configuras la fecha es llamado el método `onDateSet()`, por lo tanto, es aquí donde puedes abrir el `Spinner` mediante el método `performClick()`:

```
 date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
             ...
             ...
             ...
            mySpineer.performClick();  // * Abre Spinner.

          }

      };
```